# How to Dispose() when class is running an async loop? Wait for loop to exit?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, dispose, idisposable

I have a class that asynchronously calls a method which contains a loop.  This loop will run until the class is disposed.  When implimenting Dispose() I already have the ability to tell the loop to stop (and thus the async thread completes).  After this call to stop the loop in Dispose() should I wait for the loop to complete and the thread to die or does it not matter?  Given that I've signaled for the loop to complete, should I just continue to exit the Dispose() call?  What is the best practice here?  My loop may take a few minutes to complete once signaled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some objects have a responsibility of ensuring that entities outside them get cleaned up.  Such objects may be the only thing anywhere with the information and impetus necessary to perform such cleanup; if they don't do it, it won't happen.  IDisposable exists to allow such objects to fulfill their responsibility.

Despite its name, IDisposable doesn't exist for the purpose of destroying objects.  Rather, it exists to allow objects to put their affairs in order so that they may safely be abandoned (and eventually destroyed by the garbage-collector).  It is entirely proper for an object's Dispose method to fulfill its responsibilities by handing them off to some other entity, provided that other entity can be trusted to fulfill them.  That sounds essentially like what you're doing.

The only aspect that may be tricky in a situation like yours is deciding whether Dispose should simply set things in motion so things should get cleaned up, or whether it should stick around until they actually are.  There are substantial arguments in favor of both approaches.  Having a synchronous Dispose method is useful if the calling code needs the cleanup to have occurred before it can proceed, and may also be useful if something might go wrong in the cleanup process.  Having Dispose throw an exception is ugly (especially since there's no clean pattern by which Dispose to avoid losing any pending exception if that occurs) but trapping an exception while the execution context still exists is much nicer than finding out after the fact that some error occurred at some unknown time while doing some unknown action.  Unfortunately, using a synchronous dispose can slow down cleanup and may sometimes cause deadlock.  Using an asynchronous dispose may improve responsiveness, but code which expects that Dispose will have made something like a file or I/O device available may be surprised if the device won't be available for some time after Dispose has returned.  In some cases, it may be helpful to have an "Open" method check whether a dispose is in progress on a resource, and wait for it to complete if so.

Comment: +1.  great write-up.  I appreciate how you explored both approaches.

Answer (score 0):

If the loop is likely to be using managed resources that would end up being `Dispose`d then you must wait for the loop to complete, **then** tidy up in your `Dispose`, then exit the `Dispose` method.

Comment: @Will - my loop does in fact dispose some managed resources once signaled to stop.  @Adams response seems to say that that is inconsequential, what matters is the expectation of consuming code?

Comment: @SFun28 - if your Dispose disposes anything that the loop will consume (including any members of the class being disposed) then bad things will happen - unless you wait for the loop to stop.

Comment: My dispose will not dispose anything that the loop will dispose (what's a mouthful!).  There is a clean separation.  The classes's dispose simply tells the loop to stop.  Whenever the loop gets around to stopping it disposes a bunch of resources.  These resources are actually contained within a private member of the class and not within the loop itself - does that make a difference?

Comment: Are you comfortable calling Dispose on a class which contains a member that is referenced within the loop?

Comment: @Will - Is it poor practice?  The loop is in a method within the class.  Like any method, it should have access to private members.  It just happens that the method is called async and only ends when the class is disposed.

Comment: It might not be as bad as it feels to me - hopefully someone else can enlighten us!

Comment: @Will - upon further thought I think you are right that I should wait for the loop to complete.  It seems good that when a class completes Dispose() then all contained managed-resources are disposed.  Seems like the cleanest implementation and a reasonable expectation from consumers.

Answer (score 0):

That's a question only you can answer; if the consuming code needs to assume that after calling `Dipose` that the loop will have stopped, then wait. If not, then don't.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, shouldn't a class's code be agnostic to the manner in which the class is consumed?  A class should always "do the right thing" and not anticipate who will instantiate it.

Comment: @SFun28: A class can't be completely agnostic as to how it's being consumed; you define method signatures and nested types based upon the idea that how you're writing the class to be consumed (the API, in other words) is "right". Likewise, you have to make the choice of whether or not to terminate the loop and wait for it to complete based upon how you intend for the class to be used. You might also offer the option of specifying this behavior as a property on the class if you feel that both scenarios are valid.